# Error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: php

I have two systems `helpdesk.ops.something.in` and `dev1.ops.something.in`

I have a file `fetchP.php` in helpdesk.ops whose code goes something like this:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function someFunc(item) {
        $.ajax({method:"GET", 
        url:"http://dev1.ops.something.in/wallet/createurl.php?phone="+item, 
        success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
        });
    };
</script>';
<?php
echo '<div id="callToWallet" class="sample-button" onclick="someFunc(911234567890);"><a href="#"> Click here</a></div>';
```

which is doing a GET request to a file `createurl.php` present in the dev1.ops, which goes something like this:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');?>
<script>response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");</script>
<?php 
// the rest of the code
?>
```

But on executing, the GET request is not successful, and I am getting error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://dev1.ops.something.in/wallet/createurl.php?phone=911234567890. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://helpdesk.ops.something.in' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.`

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Comment: No, it's not. The php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); might not be present in the called php file in that one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Even with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header set, a XMLHttpRequest cannot request ressources on domains that are different from the one of your current domain (this is due to the [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)).

One way you could try to get around it is to use [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). Here's a simple and rudimentary example:

`fetchP.php` (Ajax call):

```
function someFunc(item) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        data: { phone: item },
        url: "http://localhost:2512/createurl.php", 
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        dataType: "jsonp",
    });
};
```

`createurl.php`:

```
<?php
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

  $data = ["foo" => "bar", "bar" => "baz"];
  $json = json_encode($data);

  $functionName = $_GET['callback'];

  echo "$functionName($json);";
?>
```

Example output of the `createurl.php` on an ajax request:

```
jQuery2130388456100365147_1447744407137({"foo":"bar","bar":"baz"});
```

jQuery then executes the defined function and calls the defined `success` method on the given parameters (JSON in this case).

Comment: So if I use JSONP, should it work even when the two php files are not in the same machine?

Comment: It should, that's the whole point of JSONP. When I tried this code, technically the header in the `createurl.php` wasn't even necessary.

Comment: But it is not working in here. It is hitting `http://dev1.ops.something.in/wallet/createurl.php?callback=jQuery2130056362116476520896_1447747236866&phone=911234567890&_=1447747236867`

and in the console it is showing the error: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`.

My `createurl.php` goes like this: https://paste.kde.org/pqnivzx9r

Comment: Error 500 means that it is an issue with your server `dev1.ops.something.in` or `createurl.php`. Your code works when I'm running it manually. But keep in mind that you need to output a javascript function for JSONP to work.

Comment: What do you mean by output a js function? Can you please point out in what manner is what you are returning from `createurl.php` and what I am returning, are different? This could help me in making the changes in my `createurl.php` as well. Also, you are free to suggest some direct modifications in my code as well, which you think might work. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Please take another look at my answer. When doing an AJAX call via JSONP, jQuery appends a couple of parameters including the name of a callback (in your comment this would be `jQuery21300563621164‌​76520896_1447747236866`). Therefore you need the output of your createurl.php to be this function with a parameter containing your data: `jQuery21300563621164‌​76520896_1447747236866({"response":"okay","phonenumber:"911234567890"});`. jQuery will then parse the result and execute your defined `success` function with this parameter.